# Help Import Special Character File

Tags: import

I have a text file. Get it here:
https://ufile.io/iehon

It's frensh, a subscript file and there is a lot of math. When I import it in Mathematica using:

```
subRipIm = Import[subRibFile, "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"];
subRip = DeleteCases[StringSplit[ToString[subRipIm], "\n"], ""];
```

... I can spot stuff like that:

[image]

How can I make sure that it is correctly imported ? Any help would be extremely appreciated !

Comment: Works fine on 11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018). Don't see any bad encodings.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Okay. Do you think that it is possible to convert the mathe sections of the text into Mathematica Mathe input ? I want to convert it to Latex in the end, but it does not work like that.

Comment: Remove the timing markers and numbers using `DeleteCases[subRip, s_String /; 
  StringMatchQ[
   s, {StartOfString ~~ "00" ~~ ___ , 
    StartOfString ~~ DigitCharacter ..}]]`. Looks like the math parts are delimited by <i>...</i> e.g. `<i>\[Alpha]ⱼ - \[Beta]ⱼ != 0.</i>`. Which is valid Mathematica input. Other examples are not and I think would have to be manually converted.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Many thanks for your helpful comment. I have started a new question. Maybe you can add your comment as an answer together with a bit of code of how to convert it... https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183310/convert-part-of-subscript-files-to-math-form

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem could not be reproduced and the file is not longer available behind the link.