# Convert Part of Subscript Files to Math Form

Tags: list-manipulation, import, conversion

I have french subscript file here:
https://uploadfiles.io/iehon

If you download it an open it with Word, you can see that the math sections are but between **$<i>$** and **<\i>**:

[image]

To import the file I use:

```
(*Importing*)
importSub = Import[FILEPATH, "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"];
(*Deleting empty list elements*)
subtitle = DeleteCases[StringSplit[ToString[importSub], "\n"], ""];
```

In the end I want to convert the subtitles into Latex using `TeXForm[...]` but therefore, I need to convert the parts between $<i>$ and $<\i>$ to Mathematica Math Input.

**Does anyone know how I can do that ?**

Comment: Related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183301/58370).

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but a bit long for a comment.

```
(* Positions of substrings delimited by <i>...</i> *)
delimited = StringPosition[importSub, Shortest["<i>" ~~ __ ~~ "</i>"]];

(* Extract 'math' substrings *)
math = StringTake[importSub, {First[#] + 3, Last[#] - 4}] & /@ delimited
```

I don't know anything about TeX so I cannot tell if mapping `TeXForm` on the math substrings generates the correct output or not. If it is correct, then the substrings in `importSub` can be replaced by the `TeXForm`. Deleting empty strings can be done after that.